# How to disable transition-group only on page load?

Tags: vue.js, vue-transitions

I have a transition-group that renders a div, and within that is a component with a v-for attribute that renders several items. I then have a button that adds a new item to the beginning of the array. That transition works perfectly.

The only thing I don't like, is that the entire list loads with the transition on page load, and I'd like to disable it only on page load. I've searched Stack and Google but couldn't find a way. Is there a way to do this, so that transitions still works on button click, but is disabled for page load?

```html
    <transition-group
        name="item-list"
        tag="div">
        <item-row
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.id"
            :item="item" />
    </transition-group>
```

```css
    .item-list-enter-active,
    .item-list-leave-active,
    .item-list-move {
        transition         : 250ms cubic-bezier(0.59, 0.12, 0.34, 0.95);
        transition-property: opacity, transform;
    }
    
    .item-list-enter {
        opacity  : 0;
        transform: translateX(50px) scaleY(0.5);
    }
    
    .item-list-enter-to {
        opacity  : 1;
        transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1);
    }
    
    .item-list-leave-active {
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .item-list-leave-to {
        opacity         : 0;
        transform       : scaleY(0);
        transform-origin: center top;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could've found a more "Vue-y" way of handling this, however I ended up going [this route](https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/). Essentially I added a class to the body and removed all transitions. Then on the `created` lifecycle of my component, I remove that class. This removes the transition on page load, but still keeps the transition on click of the button like I want.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this like I did.

I ended up achieving this by having a `transitionsOn` flag added to the data (didn't seem to matter what it was initialised to), and a  computed name for the transition, i.e.

```html
    <transition-group :name="transitionName">
```

in **computed**, I then had, for a transition called `'flash'`

```js
        computed: {
            transitionName() {
               return this.transitionsOn ? 'flash' : 'disabled';
            },
        },
```

I would then set `this.transitionsOn = true` when I wanted it to fire.

Took a lot of fiddling about to figure this out but it seems to work OK

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the duration for ***transition-group***

template:

```html
    <transition-group
        :duration="duration"
        name="item-list"
        tag="div">
        <item-row
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.id"
            :item="item" />
    </transition-group>
```

script:

```js
    data() {
        return {
            duration: 0,
            items: [
                {id: 1},
                {id: 2}
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        add() {
            if(this.duration===0) this.duration = 250
            this.items.push({id: 'xxx'})
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't appear to work. I still see the transition fire on page load.

Comment: Are you using the latest vue version?

Comment: Yes, it's a brand new project and is using v2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the `name` value of the transition-group. Maybe on page load have a value different from the value that has the correct class name that the CSS targets. Then in the `mounted` lifecycle hook you can change it back to the correct class name.